# Dagger 2 - what's the proper way to use the components and modules?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, dagger-2

After some playing around with [Dagger 2](http://google.github.io/dagger/), I managed to `inject` my dependencies into its dependent objects, but I am not sure its the right way of doing it, and I want to do it the proper way.

The way I did it, I have **one** `component` which includes **multiple** `modules` and I do the Injection in the top class, and the dependencies "seep" in. is that the proper way?

**App Component:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, ServiceModule.class, CallAlarmModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(HealthCheckerApplication app);
    void inject(SettingsActivity activity);
    void inject(AlertCreator alertCreator);
    void inject(HealthService service);
    INotificationDataFactory provideFactory();
}
```

**Modules:**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    HealthCheckerApplication app;
    AlertCreator alertCreator;

    public AppModule(HealthCheckerApplication app) {
        this.app = app;
        this.alertCreator = new AlertCreator(app);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public SharedPreferences provideSharedPrefs() {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(app);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public AlertCreator provideAlertCreator() {
        return alertCreator;
    }
}

@Module
public class ServiceModule {

    HealthService service;

    public ServiceModule(HealthService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public HealthService provideService() {
        return service;
    }

    @Provides
    public INotificationDataFactory provideFactory() {
        return new NotificationDataFactory();
    }

}

@Module
public class CallAlarmModule {

    IMinutesCounter.ITimerCallback timerCallBack;

    public CallAlarmModule(IMinutesCounter.ITimerCallback timerCallBack) {
        this.timerCallBack = timerCallBack;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public IMinutesCounter.ITimerCallback provideCallAlarm() {
        return timerCallBack;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public IMinutesCounter provideMinutesMonitor() {
        return new MinutesMonitor(timerCallBack);
    }
}
```

**using in code:**

**HealthService:**

```
public class HealthService extends Service {

    @Inject
    public NotificationCreator notificationCreator;

    @Inject
    public CallTooLongAlarm callTooLongAlarm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // creating all modules here (besides AppModule) and let dependencies "seep" in
        AppComponent appComponent = ((HealthCheckerApplication) getApplication()).getAppBuilder().serviceModule(new ServiceModule(this)).callAlarmModule(new CallAlarmModule(callTooLongAlarm)).build();
        appComponent.inject(this);

        notificationDataFactory = appComponent.provideFactory();
    }
}
```

**Application:**

```
public class HealthCheckerApplication extends Application {
    DaggerAppComponent.Builder appBuilder;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appBuilder = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this));
    }

    public DaggerAppComponent.Builder getAppBuilder() {
        return appBuilder;
    }
}
```

**CallTooLongAlarm:**

```
public class CallTooLongAlarm implements MinutesMonitor.ITimerCallback {

    private HealthService healthServiceContext;

    @Inject
    public IMinutesCounter minutesMonitor;

    @Inject
    public CallTooLongAlarm(HealthService context) {
        this.healthServiceContext = context;
    }
}
```

Is that how Dagger 2 **should** be used? keep in mind I access `AlertCreator` in multiple places, so I needed to make sure its the **same instance** in all places, so created it in the `AppModule`.

Comment: https://androidbolts.wordpress.com/2016/05/17/dependency-injection-with-dagger2-basic-setup/